# Why is the Lambda function added as a target to Event Bridge Rule is not triggered?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to put a rule and a lambda target to the rule for EventBridge. The rule and the target are successfully added, however, the target Lambda is not triggered. And I cannot see the relevant Trigger when I navigate to the target Lambda function on AWS Console.

I'm using **Serverless Framework** to deploy the stack. The `putRuleAndTarget` lambda is the one that creates the rule and adds `notifyUser` as the target. Here's the relevant section of the `serverless.ts` file:

```js
functions: {
      putRuleAndTarget: {
            handler: 'src/functions/putRuleAndTarget.handler',
            name: 'putRuleAndTarget'
      },
      notifyUser: {
            handler: 'src/functions/notifyUser.handler',
            name: 'notifyUser'
      }
}
```

---

This is the code for `putRuleAndTarget` (I'm using aws javascript sdk v3):

```js
import { EventBridgeClient, PutRuleCommand, PutTargetsCommand, } from '@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge'
import type { PutRuleCommandInput, PutTargetsCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge'


const client = new EventBridgeClient({ region: 'eu-central-1' })

async function putRuleAndTarget( ) {
      try {
            const putRuleCommandInput: PutRuleCommandInput = {
                  Name: 'notifyUserRule',
                  Description: 'Schedule a lambda to send notification to the user',
                  ScheduleExpression: 'rate(1 minute)',
            }
            const putRuleCommand = new PutRuleCommand(putRuleCommandInput)
            const putRuleCommandOutput = await client.send(putRuleCommand)

            const putTargetsCommandInput: PutTargetsCommandInput = {
                  Rule: 'notifyUserRule',
                  Targets: [
                        {
                              Arn: 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:AccountID:function:notifyUser',
                              Id: 'notifyUser'
                        },
                  ]
            }
            const putTargetsCommand = new PutTargetsCommand(putTargetsCommandInput)
            const putTargetsCommandOutPut = await client.send(putTargetsCommand)
      

      } catch (error) {
            console.log('[ putRuleAndTarget error ]', error)
      }

}

export const handler = putRuleAndTarget
```

---

The following screenshots are taken after running `putRuleAndTarget`
The created Rule on AWS EventBridge Console:
[The rule on EventBridge Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRag4.png)

The details of the rule showing the target:
[Rule details and Target on EventBridge Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji0LX.png)

`notifyUser` function on Lambda Console, note that the trigger is missing:
[notifyUser function on Lambda Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t70Ag.png)

---

Moreover, running `sls logs -f notifyUser` does not bring about any log statements, the function is never invoked, though it is supposed to run every 1 minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing the permissions.  The rule needs to have permission to invoke the lambda.

[This tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/integrating-amazon-eventbridge-into-your-serverless-applications/) shows the steps.  In particular, check out the portion that covers

```
AWS::Lambda::Permission
```

---

Example for request in comments:

```
 LambdaInvokePermissionsExample:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - NameOfYourLambdaResource
          - Arn
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - EventRuleResourceName
          - Arn
```

Comment: It fixed the issue, thank you. I can see that Trigger is present for the target Lambda on AWS Lambda Console. I'll be dynamically creating rules (with cron expressions) and adding the same targets. So shall I need to create a wildcard for `SourceArn` like this: `'arn:aws:events:eu-central-1:AccountId:rule/*' `

Comment: Hey folks, I have exactly the same issue, but still I haven't been able to figure out how to add such permissions (AWS::Lambda::Permission) to my serverless.yml file, it would be very helpful for me if you can provide some example on how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added an example above.